# Convert ASP.NET MVC membership to ASP.NET Core identity system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

I have a website that is using ASP.NET MVC and membership. I added another ASP.NET Core API project, and I want to use the new identity system.

My current membership login is like this:

```
 FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
 DateTime expire = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.UserName + "^" + model.Name, DateTime.Now,expire,true,string.Empty, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

 string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

 HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
 authCookie.Expires = expire;
 Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

and I add the roles to the system like this (in Global.asax) :

```
 protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
 {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                    var _repoUser = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>();

                    string username = FormsAuthentication
                     .Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                    var un = username.ToMobile();
                    string roles = _repoUser.Where(p => p.UserName == un).Single().Roles;

                    e.User = new GenericPrincipal(new 
                     System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username), roles.Split(','));
            }
        }
    }
```

and my user model is like this

[image]

My question is: how can I achieve the new identity system in my ASP.NET Core project with that user model?

Comment: so you dont have a role model? and your roles is a field in user model which is seprate with ',' ?

Comment: yes exactly @keyone2693